# Why isn't my pushKey being added to my User's post object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

When a user makes a post, I want to take the `pushKey` of the post and then add it in to the `User` object in order to store in a list of posts they have made.

I had assumed that my logic was correct but it seems not. Everything is console logging so far.

Here is the Create Post action:

```
export const createPostNoImage = (text, firstName, university, avatar) => {
  const timeDate = new Date().getTime();
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  const { uid } = currentUser;
  const anonAvatarKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  return (dispatch) => {
    const pushKey = firebase.database().ref('/social/posts/').push().key;
    const postObject = {
        text,
        comment_count: 0,
        vote_count: 0,
        author: {
          uid,
          anon_avatar_key: anonAvatarKey,
          first_name: firstName,
          photo_avatar: avatar,
          university
        },
        created_at: timeDate,
    };
    firebase.database().ref(`/social/posts/${pushKey}`)
      .update(postObject)
      .then(() => {
        postObject.uid = pushKey;

        addPostIdToProfile(pushKey);

        dispatch({ type: CREATE_POST, payload: postObject });
    });
  };
};
```

The above works just fine, I then call the `addPostIdToProfile()` function:

```
const addPostIdToProfile = (pushKey) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  console.log(pushKey);

  firebase.database().ref(`/social/users/${currentUser.uid}`)
    .update((user) => {
      if (!user.posts) {
        user.posts = {};
      }
      user.posts[pushKey] = true;

      return user;
    });
};
```

It is this that is not updating in the database. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: The `update()` method takes a JSON object as its sole parameter, not a closure like you pass in the last snippet. What do you expect that snippet to do? Where is `user` coming from?

Comment: Should I be using transaction instead?

Comment: The `transaction()` method is indeed one way  to update an existing value that avoids potential conflicts between concurrent updates.